# Why has Google Play added permissions to old app?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

This question has been asked many times, but this is different.

My very first android app is a simple stopwatch. It was made with Eclipse, takes only one java file, uses no libraries, and takes only 19Kb of memory (yes, Kilobytes!).

The app does make the phone vibrate, so the manifest includes the line:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`

However, the Google Play store [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sleepfuriously.stopwatch) now lists the permissions as:

- read phone status and identity
- read the contents of your USB storage
- modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
- read the contents of your USB storage
- modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
- read phone status and identity
- control vibration [the only valid permission]

I published the app in 2011. The min SDK is 3 (OS version 1.5 or Cupcake) as many phones back then didn't have stopwatches.

I haven't paid attention to this app in a long time. Perhaps in the intervening years Google has simply decided that anything that old has to have a bunch of permissions?

Could someone please explain this? Or provide a way to challenge Google Play's permissions? I've been getting complaints about all the permissions, and I'm mystified as to why they are included.

**UPDATE**: Google now says that this app violates their user [privacy policy](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/personal-sensitive/). They insist that I change the app, remove the app, or hire lawyers to write a privacy policy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: @MikeM.: So you're saying that there's nothing I can do as a programmer to remedy this issue, and that it's truly an error with Google Play, not something in my code or something I mis-handled when publishing/maintaining?

Comment: From your description, it sounds like something Google did on its own (though, honestly, I've not heard of anything like that before),  which we wouldn't be able to help with. However, you didn't mention anything about "maintaining" in your post. Are you really, _really_ sure you didn't change something that might be the cause? Have you tried publishing a test app, with the same setup and permissions, to see if the same thing happens?